# How to detect in class where exactly the leak happens

Tags: leakcanary

Below is the leak description provided by leakcanary sdk. From below lines not able to detect that in which line i have to make changes to get code workable as description gives only class name not the particular code.

````
ApplicationLeak(className=com.pilotflyingj.plugin.a_android.ui.component.loyalty.RewardFragment, leakTrace=
┬
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
│    Leaking: NO (InputMethodManager↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
│    GC Root: System class
│    ↓ static InputMethodManager.sInstance
├─ android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
│    Leaking: NO (DecorView↓ is not leaking and InputMethodManager is a singleton)
│    ↓ InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
├─ com.android.internal.policy.DecorView
│    Leaking: NO (View attached)
│    mContext instance of com.android.internal.policy.DecorContext, wrapping activity com.pilotflyingj.plugin.a_android.ui.component.main.MainFrameActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    Parent android.view.ViewRootImpl not a android.view.View
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ DecorView.mAttachInfo
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.View$AttachInfo
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ View$AttachInfo.mTreeObserver
│                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ViewTreeObserver
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewTreeObserver.mOnScrollChangedListeners
│                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.ViewTreeObserver$CopyOnWriteArray
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ViewTreeObserver$CopyOnWriteArray.mData
│                                        ~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array Object[].[2]
│                     ~~~
├─ com.pilotflyingj.plugin.a_android.ui.component.loyalty.-$$Lambda$RewardFragment$-e5xQ8M432-uGOrhL3ajFrvOVQg
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ -$$Lambda$RewardFragment$-e5xQ8M432-uGOrhL3ajFrvOVQg.f$0
│                                                           ~~~
╰→ com.pilotflyingj.plugin.a_android.ui.component.loyalty.RewardFragment
​     Leaking: YES (Fragment#mFragmentManager is null and ObjectWatcher was watching this)
​     key = 11be43e3-0bcf-42fb-a087-025e52576844
​     watchDurationMillis = 8225
​     retainedDurationMillis = 3220
, retainedHeapByteSize=8730107)```


How to detech exact line of leak in class. Above is the leak description provided by leakcanary sdk.
````

Answer (score 0):

Open the com.pilotflyingj.plugin.a_android.ui.component.loyalty.RewardFragment class and look for an implementation of ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener.

The leak is happening because RewardFragment is setting a OnScrollChangedListener on ViewTreeObserver but not removing it when the fragment is destroyed.

Comment: I applied this code. public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(this::onDestroyView);
    }.  but still it leaking memory with same info.

Comment: "this::onDestroyView" creates a new callback so you're not actually removing the one that was previously added.

Also you should probably do it in onDestroy() of the fragment not onDestroyView(), since the leak report is about the fragment not its view